# Convert vectors with group_by into matrix with groups as row names

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I can't seem to reshape one column of my data frame into the correct shape while retaining unique identifiers for each row. I have the following data

```
   id     x        y   indicator
1   1 249.6  1.124985        1 
2   1 250.9  1.124756        1 
3   1 252.2  1.124125        1 
4   1 253.5  1.124598        1 
5   1 254.8  1.127745        1 
6   1 256.1  1.129102        1 
7   2 249.6  2.167348        0   
8   2 250.9  2.165804        0   
9   2 252.2  2.164578        0  
10  2 253.5  2.163828        0  
11  2 254.8  2.164260        0   
12  2 256.1  2.166293        0 
13  3 249.6  0.04647765      0
14  3 250.9  0.04932262      0
15  3 252.2  0.05245448      0
15  3 253.5  0.05692405      0
17  3 254.8  0.06184551      0
18  3 256.1  0.06751989      0
```

I would like to reshape the y vector into a matrix where each row corresponds to a single y vector and there are additional columns for id and indicator, while the variable columns are labeled by the x values. Something like this:

```
id indicator  249.6      250.9      252.2      ...
1  1          1.124985   1.124756   1.124125   ...
2  0          2.167348   2.165804   2.164578   ...
3  0          0.04647765 0.04932262 0.05245448 ...
```

I've tried using the reshape function like this:

```
reshape(df[c('id','x','y')], direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "x")
```

In this case, I was just ignoring the indicator variable to see if it would work, but I got a data frame with only two columns back, the first column was ID, and the second was `y.c(249.6, 250.9, 252.2, 253.5, 254.8, 256.1, 257.4, 258.7, 260, 261.3, 262.6, 263.9, 265.2, 266.5, 267.8, 269.1, 270.4, 271.7, 273, 274.3, 275.6, 276.9, 278.2, 279.5, 280.8, 282.1, 283.4, 284.7, 286, 287.3, 288.6, 289.9, 291.2, 292.5, 293.8, 295.1,[etc]`.

I also tried using the `xtabs` function: `a = xtabs(formula = y ~ id + indicator+ x, data=df)`, but this just returned a table that looks very similar to the one I have as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é uma questão de reformatar de formato longo para largo. (Veja no SO em Inglês [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c('id', 'indicator'),
    names_from = 'x',
    values_from = 'y'
  )
## A tibble: 3 x 8
#     id indicator `249.6` `250.9` `252.2` `253.5` `254.8` `256.1`
#  <int>     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1         1  1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.13    1.13  
#2     2         0  2.17    2.17    2.16    2.16    2.16    2.17  
#3     3         0  0.0465  0.0493  0.0525  0.0569  0.0618  0.0675
```

**Dados**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
   id     x        y   indicator
1   1 249.6  1.124985        1 
2   1 250.9  1.124756        1 
3   1 252.2  1.124125        1 
4   1 253.5  1.124598        1 
5   1 254.8  1.127745        1 
6   1 256.1  1.129102        1 
7   2 249.6  2.167348        0   
8   2 250.9  2.165804        0   
9   2 252.2  2.164578        0  
10  2 253.5  2.163828        0  
11  2 254.8  2.164260        0   
12  2 256.1  2.166293        0 
13  3 249.6  0.04647765      0
14  3 250.9  0.04932262      0
15  3 252.2  0.05245448      0
16  3 253.5  0.05692405      0
17  3 254.8  0.06184551      0
18  3 256.1  0.06751989      0
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the code in the question, `indicator` should be part of the `idvar`.  Also if there are no other columns in `df` other than the 4 listed then `df[...]` could be shortened to `df`.

```
reshape(df[c('id','x','y','indicator')], direction = "wide", 
  idvar = c("id", "indicator"), timevar = "x")
```

giving:

```
   id indicator    y.249.6    y.250.9    y.252.2    y.253.5    y.254.8    y.256.1
1   1         1 1.12498500 1.12475600 1.12412500 1.12459800 1.12774500 1.12910200
7   2         0 2.16734800 2.16580400 2.16457800 2.16382800 2.16426000 2.16629300
13  3         0 0.04647765 0.04932262 0.05245448 0.05692405 0.06184551 0.06751989
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x = c(249.6, 250.9, 252.2, 253.5, 
254.8, 256.1, 249.6, 250.9, 252.2, 253.5, 254.8, 256.1, 249.6, 
250.9, 252.2, 253.5, 254.8, 256.1), y = c(1.124985, 1.124756, 
1.124125, 1.124598, 1.127745, 1.129102, 2.167348, 2.165804, 2.164578, 
2.163828, 2.16426, 2.166293, 0.04647765, 0.04932262, 0.05245448, 
0.05692405, 0.06184551, 0.06751989), indicator = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I quickly figured out my answer here using `tidyr`:

```
z = pivot_wider(df, id_cols = c("id","indicator"), names_from = "x", values_from = "y")
```

Rui Barradas's answer is the same approach, and this works perfectly.